# mysql deadlock , Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have two programs.
One is as below:

```
begin Tx;
select * from page where id=1 lock in share mode;
sleep(10);
update page.count = page.count+1 where id=1

commit;
```

the other one is :

```
update page.count = 100 where id=1;
```

I run them, the second program returns err:

```
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction 。
```

who can tell me why deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurred because both programs were trying to access the same row (id=1) in the table at the same time. The first program was locking the row in share mode, while the second program was trying to update the same row. Since they were accessing the same row, neither program could complete, resulting in a deadlock.